# No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE when running web application

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am experiencing the strange problem with `No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE`

when i run JUNIT Test case of any DAO it is inserting fine. But when i run in server it is giving `No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE`

i have added ojdbc14.jar to WEB-INF/lib folder.

here is the jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE
jdbc.username=system
jdbc.password=pwd
```

please help me.

Comment: Make sure the Oracle JDBC jar is on your classpath.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is its not loading the Oracle Driver

added this in Controller, every thing is working fine.

```
static{
    try {
        Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that for modern versions of Java and JDBC drivers this should not be necessary!

Answer (score 2):

If your database connection module is in the server, you must add the driver jar to the container, and not deploy it with your WAR.  It is a Classpath problem.

Answer (score 2):

you have to import ojdbc6.jar to the libraries like i did

1. in the left side of netbeans theres a project bar
2. right click on the libraries and select "add JAR/FOLDER"
3. then select the ojdbc.jar
4. then voilaa :D

Answer (score 0):

For beginners. Download the [ojdbc14.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-10201-088211.html) file

then right click on the folder you are working on and go to its properties

[image]

Click library, Then find the downloaded  `ojdbc14.jar` file to add it to the library

[image]

From there you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

used this as the solution, worked like a charm!! thanks Ramesh Kotha

```
 static{
        try {
            Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } }
```

Answer (score -2):

In WEB-INF/lib ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0, ojdbc8 or ojdbc6 should be there.
I have faced the same issue and resolved by this way.

See the attached.

[image: attached image]